# pip install --upgrade vs pip uninstall then install: is there ever any difference?

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi, package-managers

As far as I know:

```
pip install --upgrade pkg
```

does the same thing as:

```
pip uninstall pkg
pip install pkg
```

but now that I actually look through the docs (and `pip --help`), I can't seem to find any info that specifically confirms this assumption to be true.

Is there ever a difference in behavior/outcome between running `pip install -U ...` and running `pip uninstall ...` followed by `pip install ...`? Are there any circumstances where one workflow should be preferred over the other?

Comment: I just did an up grade yesterday and it deleted the previous version before installing the new version.

Comment: Looks like they behave identically. I've tried to see an output of this commands via `pip install --verbose --log=install_log pkg`

Answer (score 0):

I think the only difference is that the `--upgrade` version will prompt you for compatibility issues and if you decline with `n`, it will not uninstall the previous version.
In the `uninstall install` option, you end up with not having that package should you choose to 'fail' your `install` part.